# Jenkins job for multilevel maven project

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have a multi level maven project. Parent-Project, Project-A, Project-B
All the three projects have separate repositories in git (i.e Project-A and Project-B have not been added as sub modules of Parent-Project in git).

```
|- Parent-Project/
|  |- pom.xml
|- Project-A/
|  |- pom.xml
|- Project-B/
|  |- pom.xml
```

pom.xml of Parent-Project has below structure

```
<project ...>
    <modules>
        <module>../Project-A</module>
        <module>../Project-B</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

pom.xml of Project-A and Project-B have reference to Parent-Project. These project can be built only from Parent-Project. How to build a jenkins job for the Parent-Project which will checkout and build the child project?

Comment: What should Jenkins do differently than how you do it on your workstation?

Comment: I am looking for an option to add all the three projects as modules to the Jenkins job. Currently Git plugin doesn't support adding modules unlike SVN.

Comment: Do you mean submodules?

Comment: Yes, submodules.