# How to run several maven modules in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have two projects which I would like to run with maven in a Jenkins job.
In Jenkins I can add several modules from subversion, but I can only see one step for executing it with maven (where I can't choose the module...) . Any suggestion on how to execute the projects whith  maven in different steps?

Comment: Is this the same as this other (your?) question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956315/jenkins-job-for-multilevel-maven-project

Comment: (It might be similar but not the same) I have two poms with no parent pom. They are in SVN, so I can add several modules, but I do not see how to add different maven steps to run them...

Comment: Is the Jenkins job defined as a 'maven job'?

Comment: Yes, it is a maven job. (It is no problem to run a single project as a maven job).

Comment: I have used the "Parallel Test Executor Plugin" in jenkins, so I can add another jenkins task as a step of the main task. In that way, I can execute both projects with maven.